# Is "You say that" a present subjunctive expression?

Tags: subjunctives

For example

> "Look, I've got to get going. I'm due in a meeting in about twenty
>   minutes. We'll talk tonight."
>
> -"You say that, but we won't. We won't talk. We don't know how to talk anymore."

I think "You say that" is a present subjunctive because a modal verb seems to be implied between "You and say".

Comment: It's not subjunctive. "Say" is present tense, not a plain (infinitive) form.

Comment: @BillJ I'm struggling hard to understand the feeling of "You say that". This expression does not grow on me even though "He says that, but we won't" sounds perfectly natural.

Comment: It's just the 2nd-sing form of "say".

Comment: @Floret ***He*** *says that, but **he** won't.* ***I*** *say that, but **I** won't*. ***We*** *say that, but **we** won't.* ***You*** *say that but **you** won't.* The particular subject (pronoun) used doesn't change the general construction of the sentence or its sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sounds perfectly indicative to me.**

Cut out the rest of the sentence, and you have "You say that". "You" is the subject, "say" is the verb, and "that" is a direct object pronoun referring to the earlier sentence spoken. Of course, the sentence is correct anyway.

Comment: I'm struggling hard to understand the feeling of "You say that". This expression does not grow on me even though "He says that, but we won't" sounds perfectly natural.